# Do not change character sequence of an input

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html input and the value of it is equal to current date. I want to allow user adding text inside the input but to not erase the date. Can anyone help me out?

Here is the code i am using

```
<input type="text" name="entryCode" id="entryCode" />

/* get current date */
var $now = new Date();
var $month = (($now.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? ($now.getMonth()+1) : '0' +  ($now.getMonth()+1);
var $day = $now.getDate()+"";if($day.length==1) $day="0" + $day;
var $year = $now.getFullYear();
$("#entryCode").val($year + $month + $day + "-");
```

The value of input is 20140109-, i want to allow user input after the "-", keep the first 9 chars untouched.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the text outside of the input:

```
20140109-<input type="text" name="entryCode" id="entryCode" />
```

and then add then user's input to the prefix you want

**OR**

You can also use this to simulate an input with a fixed prefix **[See example here](http://jsfiddle.net/MtV4Q/1/)**

Comment: That was the easiest solution ever, my brain get stacked...How did i missed that???Thanks dude that was really helpful. I changed it to something like <span id="entryCodeDate"></span><input type="text" name="entryCode" id="entryCode" />, and $("#entryCodeDate").text($year + $month + $day + "-");. Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of the value and prevent the default behaviour:

```
$("#entryCode").on('keydown', function(e){
    var kc = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if($(this).val().length <= 9 && kc == 8){
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/A3aub/)

---

#### If you could update your markup this way:

```
<label>
    <input type="text" name="entryCode" id="entryCode" value='' />
</label>
```

You can use this code then:

```
var $now = new Date();
var $month = (($now.getMonth().length + 1) === 1) ? ($now.getMonth() + 1) : '0' + ($now.getMonth() + 1);
var $day = $now.getDate() + "";
if ($day.length == 1) $day = "0" + $day;
var $year = $now.getFullYear();
$("#entryCode").closest('label').prepend($year + $month + $day + "-").end().focus();
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/A3aub/2/)

Comment: Copy & Paste of a text longer than 8 chars will be a problem

Comment: This works for the backspace key but i still can type between date's digits

Comment: @Antegeia see the updates if you could do this way then it will help you.